# SyntaxError on using continue() as function name

Tags: python

The following is a section of code that keeps giving me a syntax error:

```
print()
continue(input('Continue? ')) #this is giving me the error on the first parentheses
```

continue() is defined later here:

```
def continue(cont):
  if cont == 'y' or cont == 'yes' or cont == 'yeah':
    print()
  elif cont == 'n' or cont == 'no':
    print('Mhm. Sure.')
    continue(input('Continue? '))
  else:
    continue(input('Continue? '))
```

I don't see how it's giving me an error, so if someone could please elaborate, that would be a huge help!

Comment: `continue` is a keyword. You can't use it as a function name.

Answer (score 4):

[`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) is a keyword. You'll have to call your function something else.